# Angular: Lazy loaded module are loaded but not rendered

Tags: angular

I have an AppModule, in which i lazy load MainModule and which lazy loads HomeModule.

MainModule is loads fine, but HomeModule is loaded, but not rendered inside router-outlet. If i load it without lazy loading, it works.

How can i make lazy loaded HomeModule render?

I've created a Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x1gcfr?file=src/app/app.module.ts

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**main.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
// import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule), // Loaded but not rendered
        // component: HomeComponent, // It works
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `Header <router-outlet></router-outlet> Footer`
})
export class MainComponent { }
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<p>Home component works!!!</p>`
})
export class HomeComponent { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loaded HomeModule wants to know how to route to the HomeComponent....

**HomeModule.ts** add:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
];
```

FYI:  It's better practice to keep your router in a different file e.g. home.router.ts

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use as less files as possible for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

When you lazy-load Angular modules, those modules have to provide routing. If you don't include it, how should Angular determine the component to load? In your case, the `HomeModule`is loaded, but which component of this module should be rendered? Sure, in your case there is only one, but in real applications you will often have multiple components in a module.

To fix your issue, you simply include routing into your `HomeModule` (just like you did in your `MainModule`):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

I edited your Stackblitz accordingly, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mbtrak?file=src/app/home/home.module.ts). You can also find more info on that in the [Angular documentation on lazy-loading modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)